# Проверить условие всего множества

Tags: oracle, plsql, sql

Уважаемые коллеги, добрый день!

Прошу помочь разобраться или дать ссылку на годным TFM по сабжу...

Есть две таблицы **t1** и **t2**.

В **t1** хранятся значения **t1_value**, **t1_key**, **t1_something**, ...

В **t2** хранятся значения **t2_value**, **t2_key**, **t2_important_value**, ...

Таблицы, связываются по условию **t1_key = t2_key**, но в таблице **t2** для для каждого **t1_key** записей может быть больше одной.

Нужно выбрать все **t1_value**, так, чтобы для каждого **t1_value** выполнялось условие **t2_important_value is null**. 
Спасибо!

Comment: Недостатоно данных.

Comment: Какие именно данные нужны? Схему рабочей базы выложить не смогу) Для каждой t1_key в t2 множество записей? Как проверить все t2_important_value на null из этого множества?

Comment: схемы нет, ловите псевдокод 
  
    having count()=sum(if(v is null,1,0))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select t1_value 
from   t1 
join   t2 
on     t1_key = t2_key 
group  by t1_value
having count(t2_important_value)=0
```

Comment: Я допер немного по другому:

    select distinct
    t1_value
    from
    t1
    left join t2 on t1_key = t2_key
    where
    t1_value not in
    (select t1_value
    from
    t1, t2
    where t1_key = t2_key
    and t2_important_value is not null);

Но ваше решение похоже на правду) Спасибо!

Comment: Только правда, ничего, кроме правды.

Answer (score 0):

```
select t1_value
from   t1, 
       t2
where  t1_key = t2_key
and    t2_important_value is null
```

Comment: Моей наивности хватило на такой select, и он не работает) Видимо, проверяется только первое t2_important_value, некоторые по t1_key не null.